# Custom font usage on a TextView in an Android widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to apply a custom ttf font on my android widget's `TextView`.

I know this is almost impossible (only solution is to render it and display as bitmap).

However the custom font I want to use is located in the apk of the launcher I'm using.

Exact path is `assets/fonts/Roboto_Thin.ttf`.

So my question: **(how) is it possible to use a custom font in a widget's TextView if this font is included in the launcher which displays the widget?**

Comment: Just include the TTF in the package.

Comment: Not possible to use ttf in widget..